# Firestore FieldValue.increment()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment()`, but `FieldValue.increment()` method is not available. I have attached an image contain available methods for `firestore.`
This is my import:

```
import firebase from "../../firebase/firebase_config"
//Usage
increment = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
```

Please assist, maybe I am missing something here.
[Firestore Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)

[Image of firebase.firestore.methods()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyHkz.png)

**EDIT 2:**
Below is the Firebase config import

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
firebaseConfig ={
...
}
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default app;
```

I did tried Doug's export and it worked, but I'm wondering why after calling `initializeApp`, the FieldValue is no longer available.
Doug's

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"

firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `FieldValue.increment()`, you have to use the export from `firebase/app`.  Whatever your `app` is in that screenshot (we can't see exactly what it is) isn't the same thing as the `firebase` exported from "firebase/app".

For version 8.x of Firebase SDKs:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"

firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1);
```

If you're doing something other than this, it won't work.

Comment: Thanks @Doug, I was able to increment using what you provided, I make an edit to ask why after calling `initializeApp`, the FieldValue is no longer available

Comment: The `app` you get from calling `initializeApp` is not equivalent to the `firebase` that's exported from fireabse/app.  You have to use the exported symbol.