# Getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined" when trying to update an array in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm receiving the following error message when trying to update an array in cloud firestore:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'arrayUnion' of undefined`

Here is my code along with my firebase config:

```
import fire from '../config/Firebase';
  
let tweetToUpdate = 'example-value';

fire.firestore().collection("liked-tweets")
  .doc(userID)
  .update({
    tweets: fire.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(tweetToUpdate),
    });
```

Firebase.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const CONFIG = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "twitter-clone-c1b85.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "twitter-clone-c1b85",
  storageBucket: "twitter-clone-c1b85.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "987719332990",
  appId: "1:987719332990:web:2fde4fb30d70bcf0bb542f",
  measurementId: "G-T347VWPPJM",
};

const fire = firebase.initializeApp(CONFIG);

export default fire;
```

Going by the error message, it would suggest the 'fire.firestore' object is undefined and therefore does not have a property named 'FieldValue'. However, should my 'fire' not have a 'firestore' object?

Other methods like fire.firestore(), fire.storage() work fine.

I suspect it has something to do with how I'm exporting/importing firebase but I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

I've tried some related SO threads e.g [Firestore arrayUnion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230367/firestore-arrayunion) but have not found an answer that works.

Here are the docs I've been following: [Update elements in an array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thanks.

Comment: It'd be easier if you could post the whole error stack. There's no `arrayUnion` in your code but we could possibly find where the error originated from your code with the whole stack.

Comment: @MinusFour Hey, thanks for your reply. The error stack began on line 8 of my first code block. There is an arrayUnion method there. Sorry if I misunderstood your Q.

Comment: So my guess would then be there's something wrong with the document you are retrieving. Maybe it doesn't exist?

Comment: @MinusFour I managed to find a solution, see below. Thanks for taking a look though!

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to get it working by importing the following:

`import firebase from 'firebase/app'`

Thanks to the following SO [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65273383/firestore-fieldvalue-increment?rq=1)

Seems when you want to access the 'firestore' object you need to import from 'firebase/app'.